# Tensorflow shuffle batch fraction unexpected behavior

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I am training a convolutional neural network and I got some unexpected behavior with the shuffle_batch fraction summary, or maybe I just do not understand it. Can someone pls explain it? The difference between those two graphs is that I exchanged the loss function.

With this loss function I get the line at 0.0

```
loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(expected_labels-labels)
```

While this one gives me a constant 1.0 (after hitting 1.0 the first time)

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(expected_labels - labels))
```

Can the change of loss function really cause that change? I am not sure what this means.

[image: plot]

EDIT: Code as requested
The first part is for setting up the batching and the big picture.

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames,
                                                num_epochs=None)
label, image = read_and_decode_single_example(filename_queue=filename_queue)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image.values[0], channels=3)
jpeg = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.
jpeg.set_shape([66,200,3])
images_batch, labels_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [jpeg, label], batch_size= FLAGS.batch_size,
    num_threads=8,
    capacity=60000,
    min_after_dequeue=10000)
images_placeholder, labels_placeholder = placeholder_inputs(
    FLAGS.batch_size)

label_estimations, W1_conv, h1_conv, current_images = e2e.inference(images_placeholder)

# Add to the Graph the Ops for loss calculation.
loss = e2e.loss(label_estimations, labels_placeholder)


# Decay once per epoch, using an exponential schedule starting at 0.01.


# Add to the Graph the Ops that calculate and apply gradients.
train_op = e2e.training(loss, FLAGS.learning_rate, FLAGS.batch_size)
```

Here come the methods for inference loss and train

```
def inference(images):
with tf.name_scope('conv1'):
    W_conv1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 3, FEATURE_MAPS_C1], stddev=STDDEV))
    b_conv1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(BIAS_INIT, shape=[FEATURE_MAPS_C1]))
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.bias_add(
        tf.nn.conv2d(images, W_conv1, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID'), b_conv1)

with tf.name_scope('conv2'):
    W_conv2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, FEATURE_MAPS_C1, 36], stddev=STDDEV))
    b_conv2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(BIAS_INIT, shape=[36]))
    h_conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(h_conv1, W_conv2, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID') + b_conv2

with tf.name_scope('conv3'):
    W_conv3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 36, 48], stddev=STDDEV))
    b_conv3 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(BIAS_INIT, shape=[48]))
    h_conv3 = tf.nn.conv2d(h_conv2, W_conv3, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID') + b_conv3

with tf.name_scope('conv4'):
    W_conv4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 48, 64], stddev=STDDEV))
    b_conv4 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(BIAS_INIT, shape=[64]))
    h_conv4 = tf.nn.conv2d(h_conv3, W_conv4, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID') + b_conv4

with tf.name_scope('conv5'):
    W_conv5 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 64, 64], stddev=STDDEV))
    b_conv5 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(BIAS_INIT, shape=[64]))
    h_conv5 = tf.nn.conv2d(h_conv4, W_conv5, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID') + b_conv5
    h_conv5_flat = tf.reshape(h_conv5, [-1, 1 * 18 * 64])


with tf.name_scope('fc1'):
    W_fc1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1 * 18 * 64, 100], stddev=STDDEV))
    b_fc1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(BIAS_INIT, shape=[100]))
    h_fc1 = tf.matmul(h_conv5_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1

with tf.name_scope('fc2'):
    W_fc2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([100, 50], stddev=STDDEV))
    b_fc2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(BIAS_INIT, shape=[50]))
    h_fc2 = tf.matmul(h_fc1, W_fc2) + b_fc2

with tf.name_scope('fc3'):
    W_fc3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([50, 10], stddev=STDDEV))
    b_fc3 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(BIAS_INIT, shape=[10]))
    h_fc3 = tf.matmul(h_fc2, W_fc3) + b_fc3

with tf.name_scope('fc4'):
    W_fc4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10, 1], stddev=STDDEV))
    b_fc4 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(BIAS_INIT, shape=[1]))
    h_fc4 = tf.matmul(h_fc3, W_fc4) + b_fc4


return h_fc4
```

Here is the loss function, using l2 causes the issue.

```
def loss(label_estimations, labels):    
    n_labels = tf.reshape(label_estimations, [-1])
    # Here are the two loss functions
    #loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(n_labels - labels))
    loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(n_labels-labels)
    return loss
```

Train method:

```
def training(loss, learning_rate, batch_size): 
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
    tf.scalar_summary('learning_rate',learning_rate)
    tf.scalar_summary('Loss ('+loss.op.name+')', loss)

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
    return train_op
```

Plot for `tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(n_labels - labels)/2)`

[image: Imgur]

Comment: please provide whole code (both codes) as this should not happen and looks like a small mistake somewhere else (invalid sign somewhere).

Comment: Added everything you need hopefully, but let me tell you again that the only thing I change to get these results is the loss function!! Oh and what is the plot actually saying? because in both cases the time for one iteration is the same.

Comment: please try `tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(n_labels - labels)/2)` too and add a plot

Comment: @lejlot looks like l2

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in TensorFlow's original guide https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data

> How many threads do you need? the tf.train.shuffle_batch* functions add a summary to the graph that indicates how full the example queue is. If you have enough reading threads, that summary will stay above zero. You can view your summaries as training progresses using TensorBoard.

It seems better if the queue is never empty, i.e. the "fraction_full" stays non-zero. If not, you should allocate more threads to `queue_runner`

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between your loss and `l2` is scaling, thus you might need to play around with your learning rate / other hyperparameters to take this into account.

l2 loss in TF is defined as:

```
1/2 SUM_i^N (pred(x_i) - y_i)^2
```

while your cost is

```
1/N SUM_i^N (pred(x_i) - y_i)^2
```

Of course since you are using stochastic gradient approach, efficienty you are using an approximator of form

```
1/2 SUM_{(x_i, y_i) in batch} (pred(x_i) - y_i)^2 # l2
1/#batch SUM_{(x_i, y_i) in batch} (pred(x_i) - y_i)^2 # you
```

Thus you would have to multiply your cost by `batch_size / 2` to get the original cost. Typically this is not a problem, but sometimes wrong scaling can put you in very degenerated parts of the error surface, and the optimizer will simply fail (especially such aggressive one like Adam).

Side note - you are aware that your model is a deep **linear** model? You do not have any non-linearities in the model. This is very specific network.

Comment: Yeah it is linear right now but it is not working as it should. What kind of activation function would you propose for this kind of network. It needs to recognize outlines of a road.

Comment: I am also wondering what the huge difference in the plots actually means !?

Comment: It means nothing besides lack of stability. You would have to track exactly your gradients to see what went wrong.